# Always set working directory to Dropbox folder on any machine

Tags: r, path, directory

I wanted to have a simple code at the beginning of my scripts to set the working directory to my Dropbox folder, regardless of which machine I run my code on:

```
setdir <- function(){
  wandir <- paste(path.expand("~"), "/Dropbox/_R", sep = "")
  curdir <- getwd()
  if(curdir!=wandir){
    setwd(wandir)
  }
}
setdir()
```

The trick with the `path.expand("~")` works on Linux machines, but it doesn't on Windows machines, because it leads to `C:/Users/username/Documents` instead of `C:/Users/username/`. Is there a function that would work globally?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a hacky workaround, which is far from a global one:

```
setdir <- function(){
  wandir <- paste(path.expand("~"), "/Dropbox/_R", sep = "")
  wandir <- sub("/Documents", "", wandir)
  curdir <- getwd()
  if(curdir!=wandir){
    setwd(wandir)
  }
}
setdir()
```